# Why am I not POSTing data to database Django/Python

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I am unable to get the data to my database  ***am I missing something***. Followed a couple tutorials, tried my own tweaking but no luck thus far. I m not getting any errors but when I click submit on the form my database is not populating.

**My View**

```
def createUser(request):
    # form = UserForm()
    args = {}    

    if request.method=='POST':
        userform = UserForm(request.POST)
        petform = PetForm(request.POST)

        if userform.is_valid() and petform.is_valid():
            newuser = userform.save()
            newpet = petform.save(False)

            newpet.newuser = newuser
            newpet.save()
            return render(request, 'pet_list.html' )
    else:
        userform = UserForm()
        petform = PetForm()

    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['userform'] = userform
    args['petform'] = petform
    return render(request, 'add_user_pet.html', args)
```

**My Template**

```
  <form action="/ " method="POST" >
    {% csrf_token %} 
    <h3 class="details">User Info</h3>
      {{userform}}
      <h3 class="details">Pet Info</h3>
      {{petform}}

  <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
```

**Form.py**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = NameField()
    email = forms.CharField(label='E-mail',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Whats your email"}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['name', 'email']

#################################################


class PetForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = [
            'name', 
            'submitter',
            'species',
            'breed',
            'description',
            'sex',
            'age'
            ]
```

My Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('user_list', views.userlist, name='userlist'),
    path('pet_list', views.petList, name='petlist'),
    path('user_pet', views.userPet, name='userpet'),
    path('add_user_pet', views.createUser, name='add_user_pet')
    path('user_detail/<int:user_id>', views.userdetail, name='detail'),
```

Comment: Share your `urls.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form action points to "/" which is going to home view but you want to call "add_user_pet" to direct your POST to createUser view.

```
 <form action="/ " method="POST" >
```

should be

```
 <form action="add_user_pet" method="POST" >
```

the more "django" way would be to not put the url directly but use the name of the path as you defined it in urlspatterns:

```
 <form action="{% url 'add_user_pet' %}" method="POST" >
```

in this way you are using the urlspatterns name.

Comment: Tried this but still not populating database.

Comment: 1) do you see the POST request in your server terminal?  2) do you get the pet_list.html rendered?  3) what is the result of your is_valid() checks .... I would debug with prints to see what happens step by step

Comment: Trying this approach....will let you know the outcome

Comment: I can now see the requested data in my terminal and the pet_list is now being rendered. But for some reason form aint valid....

Comment: thank you. It now works.......in my views file I changed newpet.newuser to newpet.user. as 'user;' is the foregn key in my Pet model. Also fixed some tab spaces. That along with your input solved it.